# .change on form with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change a form with jquery but I can't do what I want...

I have a form with a list of product. Each product has an `input type="number"` for quantity and a second input for percentage.

When the user change the input, the price of each product is caculate in jquery with : `$('#products input').on('change', function(){ ... });`

It's working well.

But at the bottom of my form, I have two other `input type="number"` with quantity and percentage and when a user change this input, all inputs for product quantity (or percentage) is changed. But the `.on('change')` on my form isn't actived so the price isn't actualised.

I'm lost... I looking for trigger but its doesn't run.

If someone see a solution...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#products input').on('change', function(){
    $(this).parents('form').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: I think that I understand when you want to go... The solution may be is to call the global form change after the call of my bottom input to set all quantity.. 

But its doesn't run...

Answer (score 0):

You should bind key events :

```
.on('keypress', function(){});
```

Comment: I found an other solution... I call a refresh function on form change and on input change. Its maybe not the better solution but it's running.

This function loop on each input in the form to actualize it.